# Prevent NavigationLink from processing state variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

I don't like my title, but it's the best I could think of.  Basically, I have two Views:  SearchInput and SearchResultList.  The user enters a search term with SearchInput, taps "Go" and then sees the results of the search with SearchResultList.  The code is:

```
struct SearchInput: View {
    @State private var searchTerm: String = ""

    var searchResult: [RTDocument] {
        return RuntimeDataModel.shared.fetchRTDocuments(matching: self.searchTerm)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter search term...", text: self.$searchTerm)

                NavigationLink(destination: SearchResultList(
                    rtDocuments: self.searchResult
                )) { Text("Go") } //NavigationLink
            } //VStack
        } //NavigationView
    } //body
} //SearchInput
```

The issue I'm having is that every time the user enters a character in TextField, the bound-state variable searchTerm is updated which causes NavigationLink to reevaluate its destination -- which causes a Core Data fetch up in the computed searchResult variable.

I'd like the fetch to happen only once, when the user taps "Go".  Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, so in general you should redesign your SearchResultList, but this can help as a walkaround:

Declare a state on your input:

```
@State var shouldNavigate = false
```

Then separate the button form the navigation link.

```
Group {         
    Button("Go") {
        self.shouldNavigate = true
    }
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("SearchResultList"),
                   isActive: $shouldNavigate) {
        EmptyView()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  When you say redesign, do you mean I should send just the searchTerm (String) to SearchResult List, and then have SearchResultList do the fetching?

Comment: I think you should pass something into your SearchResultList that doesn't cause a CoreData fetch and kick off a fetch in .onAppear. Maybe just the search term?